# Pull out data from a specific month in Netsuite

Tags: date, plsql, netsuite

Trying to extract data from every months of the year.
I haven't seen much info on it.

I tried many formulas but nothing worked. Stuff like:

```
CASE {trandate} WHEN 'YYYY' = '2018' AND 'MM' = "01" then {amount} ELSE 0 END
```

Anyone knows how to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but the syntax for a `case` expression is either `case x when y then z` or `case when x = y then z`, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your example and correcting (note William Robertson's comment):

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') = '2018' AND TO_CHAR({trandate},'MM') = '01' THEN {amount} ELSE 0 END
```

This will return `{amount}` for every transaction in January 2018 which matches the criteria you have set.  However, if you want to return amount for *all* months, you'd probably be better off doing something like:

- Sum by `{amount}`
- Group by a formula(text) field with a formula like:

  `TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY') || TO_CHAR({trandate},'MM')`

This can be tweaked to give a more readable result (for instance by concatenating with a hyphen, or using month names instead of number etc.) but this should get you started.

EDIT: A better way to write the formula for the first method would be:

```
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR({trandate},'YYYY-MM') = '2018-01' THEN {amount} ELSE 0 END
```

Also - the first method is best if you want to group amounts by month into columns, whereas the second would give you amounts for each month in different rows of the result page.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I tried to extract the amount from month of Jan, than Feb, etc. so the first formula works perfectly and I'll repeat it for every month.

Thanks