# Case When X, then sum Y for Results tab

Tags: sql, netsuite

I would like to create a formula field on results tab that sums projected total IF the Opportunity has been won "this month".  I'll be doing the same for lost opportunities and created opportunities but i can't get my formula to work:
Using a formula numeric or formula text field-

```
sum (Case when {opportunity.closedate}= this month),  {projectedamount}
```

Any advice on how to adjust to work?

Comment: Is that your real SQL code? If not, please show everything and not in a pseudo-code form like it looks like now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632032/pull-out-data-from-a-specific-month-in-netsuite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a saved search, rather than including `sum()` in your formula, you should set the Summary Type to "Sum".  You should also set the field to `Formula (Currency)`, as that is what's being returned by the formula (sometimes other formula types will work, but the general rule is that the formula type must match the data type of what the formula will return).

With that done, you can compare the month and year of the date field to the current month and year to get this month, or perform simple date arithmetic to get last month, or any other period.  For 'this month':

```
case when to_char({opportunity.closedate}, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM') then {projectedamount} else 0 end
```

HTH.